# PHP Delimiting Quotation marks

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP comment system and came across the problem that the commentator's quotation marks are delimited when written to the comment file, so the output would end up like this for example:
"That is your father\'s! It\'s special to him!" (random sentence). How do I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslashes are added to the database query to prevent SQL injection. You can use the [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) function to remove them when you retrieve the comments from the database.

You should also take a look at [magic quotes](http://php.net/magic_quotes).

Comment: I used stripslashes() and it worked beautifully.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on version of PHP and it's configuration. Older versions (older than 5.3) had this enabled by default. It adds the quotes when you post your comment (so it will be stored in the database with the quotes). You can disable this behavior:

http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php

http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php

http://cz.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

For existing comments, you'll have to run some cleanup script that will fetch all rows, performs `stripslashes()` on it and save it back.
Escaping your queries should be done by `mysql_real_escape()` anyway, relying on magic quotes is suicide, so if you think about it, it's safer to turn them off completely and escape the queries manually.

Answer (score 1):

Turn gpc_magic_quote 's off in your php.ini .

Answer (score 0):

Those backslashes are there to *escape* the quotation marks from the SQL engine.

That style of programming is quite common with the `mysql_*` series of functions which take a *string* directly from the program and execute it directly in the database engine. This is notoriously prone to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection_attack) and, as you've discovered, corrupting your data. (When applied *consistently*, you can always de-corrupt the data on the way back to the user, with the `stripslashes()` function, but that *also* must be done consistently.)

The far better approach in my humble opinion is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and let the database libraries insert data directly into the database without any escaping or un-escaping involved. This also completely removes the risk of SQL injection attacks. (Though you're still free to write insecure code.)